# Prevent Visual Studio on Mac from opening new tabs in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-mac

Every time I run my program (Start without debugging) Visual Studio opens a new tab in the terminal is there any way to let it run every time in the same tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure your application when it is run it outputs everything to the Application Output window instead of opening a terminal window. To do this:

1. Right click your project in the Solution window and select Options.
2. Open Run - Configurations - Default.
3. Uncheck Run on external console.
4. Click OK to save changes.

Note that if you need console input, for example you use Console.ReadKey, then this approach will not work since the Application Output window is not a real console window.

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much, everything as described.